# Understanding the denominator for a multivariate Gaussian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

I am learning about multivariate Gaussians. In [this video](https://youtu.be/eho8xH3E6mE?t=127) the speaker says that the denominator, $$2\pi^{D/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}$$ is a constant that ensures the pdf integrates to 1. I understand why the pdf must integrate to 1 but not how the constant ensures that this is so. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

In a univariate gaussian, you have the denominator:

$$ \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma $$

What this does is correct for the amount of "stretching" that is done by the $\sigma$ term in the exponential function $e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. Why is this? Because the above denominator is a simple example of a [Jacobian Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant), which is used to ensure that an integral does not change when you go to a new set of (transformed) variables. We can see this as follows. If $F_{\mu,\sigma}(x)$ is the cdf of your univariate gaussian, then we know that it is related to the integral of the standard gaussian by a shift and scale transformation:

$$F_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) $$

However, the above has a problem: The RHS does not integrate to 1! It is too wide. We need to uniformly reduce the height of the function by some factor to get it to work out. This factor is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\sigma$, where $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. With this factor, we can now re-write (correctly) our transformed standard gaussian:

$$ F_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \implies f_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=\frac{d}{dz}F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

The above will now integrate to 1, since we have removed the effect of stretching the standard gaussian by $\sigma$. Taking that intuition to the multivariate case, you will be forming the Jacobian matrix of your transformation, which will be equal to the first derivative of each of the original variables wrt each transformed variable, for an $n \times n$ matrix). The determinant of this will be the degree of "stretching" done by your transformation, just like in the univariate case.

However, the notation in your post is not in terms of the jacobian, but of the coveriance matrix, whose determinant is the square of the stretching factor. Hence, you take the square root.

Ill leave it as an exercise for you to use the definition of the Jacobian in the wiki link to derive the details..its a bit of tedious algebra, but it will give you the equation in your post (once you verify that $|\Sigma|=|J|^2$

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. I don't know any vector calculus  but it seems like I need to learn some to understand the Gaussian equation.

Comment: @bernie2436 yea..vector calc is essential if you're studying multivariate stats